# Explanation of the C++ template function argument deduction when matching `T const &&t` against `int const *`

Tags: c++, templates, constants, template-argument-deduction

I don't understand how the argument deduction rule works in this case. I have the following simple code snippet:

```
template<typename T>
void fn(T const &&t) {
   std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__  << std::endl;
   std::cout << typeid(decltype(t)).name() << std::endl;
}
int main() {
   int const *ar = nullptr;
   std::cout << typeid(ar).name() << std::endl;
   fn(std::move(ar));
}
```

The result I get is as follows:

```
PKi
void fn(const T &&) [T = const int *]
PKi
```

What I don't understand is why `T` is inferred as `const int *`. Why the `const` did not get pattern matched?

Comment: which `const` did not get matched?

Comment: The `const` in the template parameter `const T&&` and the one in `const int *`. I was expecting that `T` becomes `int *` and not `const int *`.

Comment: Does `void fn(T const* &&t)` produce what you expected?

Comment: But `const int*` != `int* const`.

Comment: I think they are @Evg

Comment: No, they are different types.

Comment: perhaps what you mean is that `int const *` and `int * const` are different types.

Comment: @Amir `int const *` and `const int *` are same, `const int *` and `int * const` are different, putting `const` before or after `*` makes difference.

Comment: A short talk that you might find interesting: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fv--IKZFVO8

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the parameter declaration `T const &&t`, `const` is qualified on `T`, i.e. `t` is declared as an rvalue-reference to `const T`.

When `ar` with type `const int *` is passed, `T` is deduced as `const int *`, then the type of `t` would be `const int * const &&`, i.e. an rvalue-reference to `const` pointer to `const int`. Note that the `const`s are qualified on different things (on different levels), one for the pointer, one for the pointee.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Why is `T` deduced as `const int *`. Probably I don't understand `typeid` properly. The snippet shows that the type of `t` is the same as the type of `ar` and there is no extra const.

Comment: @Amir Yes, for [`typeid`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid), *If type is a reference type, the result refers to a std::type_info object representing the referenced type.* *In all cases, top-level cv-qualifiers are ignored by typeid*

Comment: @Amir As the result, `typeid(const int*) == typeid(const int * const &&)` is `true`.